# "Workflow failed. Causes: Network default is not accessible to Dataflow Service account or does not exist"

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I deleted my default network and working on my own custom network.
I imported training data set in Google cloud datalab. When I try to run python code to create ML data set using Dataflow I am getting above error.

Training set I imported is babyweight.

I created instance for datalab in custom network by giving *--subnetwork=custom subnet* variable

Firewall already open for all ports and all sources on the network.

Service account for Dataflow service agent and cloud ml service agent also have *compute network user* role.

I also try to set subnetwork variable with complete URL in python code as well as on *os.envrion['subnetwork']*.

But whenever click on RUN cell I get same error. Can you help me out how to resolve this error.
I can create default network again but I am doing this for learning purpose.
Can you help me out to resolve the issue

Comment: In order to investigate further could you share your python code and the full error message?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reaching. I am able to resolve the issue.I was passing the subnetwork in wrong parameters. After adding subnetwork in pipeline argument issue got resolve. Now I am able to run the job.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding subnetwork variable in pipeline options in wrong way. Issue got resolve after correcting the parameters.